# org.graalvm.compiler.java: UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of org.bson.BsonDocument are allowed in the image heap

Tags: micronaut, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

Trying to create native image on micronaut application with Graal VM `22.1.0.r17` using gradle command as

```
./gradlew nativeCompile
```

but getting an exception as

```
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of org.bson.BsonDocument are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=org.bson.BsonDocument.
        at parsing io.micronaut.data.mongodb.operations.DefaultMongoStoredQuery.<init>(DefaultMongoStoredQuery.java:164)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.throwParserError(BytecodeParser.java:2505)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase$SharedBytecodeParser.throwParserError(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:105)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.iterateBytecodesForBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3366)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.handleBytecodeBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3318)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.processBlock(BytecodeParser.java:3163)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.build(BytecodeParser.java:1138)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser.buildRootMethod(BytecodeParser.java:1030)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.java.GraphBuilderPhase$Instance.run(GraphBuilderPhase.java:84)
        at com.oracle.svm.hosted.phases.SharedGraphBuilderPhase.run(SharedGraphBuilderPhase.java:79)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.run(Phase.java:49)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.BasePhase.apply(BasePhase.java:236)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:42)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.phases.Phase.apply(Phase.java:38)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.AnalysisParsedGraph.parseBytecode(AnalysisParsedGraph.java:135)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.ensureGraphParsed(AnalysisMethod.java:586)


Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError: parsing had failed in another thread
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError.shouldNotReachHere(AnalysisError.java:176)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.meta.AnalysisMethod.ensureGraphParsed(AnalysisMethod.java:621)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.lookupEncodedGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:180)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.doInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1145)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.tryInline(PEGraphDecoder.java:1128)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.trySimplifyInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:982)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.handleInvoke(PEGraphDecoder.java:936)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.processNextNode(GraphDecoder.java:788)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysisGraphDecoder.processNextNode(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:240)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.nodes.GraphDecoder.decode(GraphDecoder.java:529)
        at jdk.internal.vm.compiler/org.graalvm.compiler.replacements.PEGraphDecoder.decode(PEGraphDecoder.java:812)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.phases.InlineBeforeAnalysis.decodeGraph(InlineBeforeAnalysis.java:98)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.parse(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:174)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlowBuilder.apply(MethodTypeFlowBuilder.java:357)
        at com.oracle.graal.pointsto.flow.MethodTypeFlow.createTypeFlow(MethodTypeFlow.java:301)
```

other cause as well

```
Caused by: org.graalvm.compiler.java.BytecodeParser$BytecodeParserError: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of org.bson.BsonDocument are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=org.bson.BsonDocument.

Caused by: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: No instances of org.bson.BsonDocument are allowed in the image heap as this class should be initialized at image runtime. To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=org.bson.BsonDocument


Fatal error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.util.AnalysisError$ParsingError: Error encountered while parsing io.micronaut.data.mongodb.operations.DefaultMongoStoredQuery.<init>(io.micronaut.data.model.runtime.StoredQuery, org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry, io.micronaut.data.model.runtime.AttributeConverterRegistry, io.micronaut.data.model.runtime.RuntimeEntityRegistry, io.micronaut.core.convert.ConversionService, io.micronaut.data.model.runtime.RuntimePersistentEntity, java.lang.Object)
```

However, this error doesn't occur with micronaut compilation, I have these dependencies in the project

```
implementation("io.micronaut.data:micronaut-data-mongodb:3.3.0")
    implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:4.6.0-alpha0'
```

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug on micronaut data https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/1504

**work around**

```
graalvmNative {
    binaries {
        main {
            imageName.set('mn-graalvm-fetebird-product') 
            buildArgs.add('--verbose')
            buildArgs.add('--initialize-at-build-time=org.bson.codecs.jsr310.Jsr310CodecProvider,org.bson.codecs.BsonTypeClassMap,org.bson.codecs.BsonValueCodecProvider,org.bson.BsonDocument')
        }
    }
}
```